# Configuring Visual State Setters for a Style Universal Windows App

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I have a UWP app where I have created various styles for buttons and textblocks that are being used in different pages. I had assumed that I will be able to apply Visual State setters on the styles itself. However, it seems that the setters in Visual State can only be applied directly to a specific control. Is there any way to apply Visual State to an Style elements. I have 60 textblocks in my pages that have all a particular font size. Do I have to go and specify a different font size for everyone of these controls to use Visual State or is there a simpler way to do it.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Your 60 textblocks all have a particular fontsize? Each one's fontsize is different? Or they can be sorted into several groups with several different fontsize?

Comment: The 60 textblocks all have a particular font size for the screen size. For e.g. 15 for mobile and 24 for desktop. I was using Text Block as one example. I will have to do the same thing for buttons textbox etc.

Comment: OK, then you can use data binding for this, like the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should take a difference approach: Bind the font size of 60 TextBlock to a property, and update + notify it when your condition triggered in code behind.

in XAML:

```
<TextBlock FontSize={"Binding MyFontSize"}/>
<!-- 60 of your textblock here ...... -->
```

in your ViewModel, I use MVVM Light to notify the property changed event:

```
private double _MyFontSize = null;

    public double MyFontSize
    {
        get
        {
            return _MyFontSize;
        }
        set
        {
            Set(ref _MyFontSize, value);
        }
    }
```

In your code behind:
in contructor:

```
this.SizeChanged += LoginPanel_SizeChanged;

private void LoginPanel_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.NewSize.Width >= 600)
        {
            (this.DataContext as MyViewModel).MyFontSize = 20;
        }
        else
        {
            (this.DataContext as MyViewModel).MyFontSize = 16;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more details? How do I trigger the visual state based on a property. Just to clarify I am using visual state to support different screen sizes

Comment: you dont trigger the visual state trigger. You notify the property changed (from your DataContext). In your case, subscribe to SizeChanged event of the Page and react accordingly.

Comment: I am sorry I am new to the whole UWP model. Can you share some code sample how to do this?